# MySQL: How can we dynamically choose an appropriate type?

Tags: mysql, variables, dynamic, types

1. Is there such an opportunity? Let's say, we have a range of integers. We loop over them and find out that they don't exceed 65535. So, now we know that `SMALLINT` would be a suitable type and are going to create a table with a column of the appropriate type! How can we do this?

2. I've tried various combinations like:

   ```
   SET @ty := "INT";

   CREATE TABLE tab (
     id @ty
   );
   ```

   but they all have failed and ended up complaining on `@ty`.
   So, the other question is whether we can keep in a server script `@variable` (as `INT` or as `"INT"`)?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: The datatype must be defined by the entity properties, not by current values set. *I've tried various combinations like* Study dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement).

Comment: @Akina what do you mean by *entity properties*? Thanks for the information about *PREPARE*!

Comment: *what do you mean by entity properties?* The database is a model of some real things and processes. These things and processes have some properties which are defined by their essenses. The column which will store this thing/process property must accept any property value which is possible, even when this value is absent in current datatset.

Comment: @Akina I've surfed the Web and it seems like MySQL's core ideas are implemented as *essences* (which are MySQL data pieces as well), aren't they?

Comment: @Akina but is there any possible way to refer to *entity properties defined by their essences* (via `@variables` or via special queries)? For now, it seems like we cannot both address to types like `INT` themselves in any manner as well as we cannot keep those anywhere in any possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By ***loop over them and find out that they don't exceed 65535*** ,if you mean the highest values does not exceed 65535, then we can use max() function to get the highest value. If you mean the number of values within the range, the count() function should be used instead. Next we can perform a condition check to determine which numeric type should be used. The rest is to create the wanted table based on the result from the condition check using PREPARED STATEMENT. To illustrate , we create a table and insert values to simulate the number range. Then use a procedure to create the intended table dynamically.

```
create table numbers (n int);
insert numbers values(1),(2),(70000);

delimiter //
drop procedure if exists create_table //
create procedure create_table()
begin
declare num_range int;
select max(n) from numbers into num_range; -- supposing you mean the highest values does not exceed 65535
If num_range<65536 then
    set @create_tb_stmt=concat('create table `tab` (id smallint);');
    else 
    set @create_tb_stmt=concat('create table `tab` (id int);');
end if;

drop table if exists `tab` ;
PREPARE stmt FROM @create_tb_stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;

end//
call create_table // -- call the procedure to make it happen
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is a wonderful solution! Although, seems like we cannot keep the types like `INT` anywhere in any possible way?

Comment: It seems like we can keep "reference" to types like `INT` themselves in a string like `@int_rfr = "INT"` and later use it in `PREPARE CONCAT(..., @int_rfr, ...)`. And it is probably enough because it seems like we always address to types like `INT` only in an SQL query.